# Orders / Transactions / Charge Square Connect

Tags: javascript, php, e-commerce, square-connect

What are the steps that I need to follow to properly charge a customer using square-connect?

I'm confused because the documentation is not very clear about this.

- Do I have to create an Order object then do a Transactions and the Charge?
- Do a Transactions and then charge?
- Can charge directly?

Answer (score 1):

Generally your workflow is to create a `card_nonce` using the [payment form](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/sqpaymentform/sqpaymentform-overview), and then send that to the [`charge`](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-charge) endpoint with the amount you want to charge.

```
Create card nonce -> Charge
```

If you want itemizations for your transaction, you can optionally create an order as well

```
Create card nonce -> Create Order -> Charge
```

Comment: so basically you charge costumer with an amount without registering which items he bought? That "step" is like optional

Comment: For the first option, the second includes the item information so you can see the items purchased in the receipt and dashboard.

Comment: Thanks for response me, Which method you encourage me to use?

Comment: If you only have one item, use the first option. If you have lots of items, use the second.